# Moisture of the product

Tags: candy, moisture

I noticed that after some time the gummy bears are really sticky after eating one of the packets of gummy bears and having them glued to my hands. Where does that moisture comes from and what is the cause? What changes can be implemented in the recipe to avoid higher humidity in the final product?

Comment: You did not mention there is a sugar/acid coating. That changes things a bit. See linked question http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/60302/making-super-sour-sweets-issues-with-stickiness/60414#60414

Answer (score 0):

Its likely that :

- (1)the packet you ate had a small hole in it
- (2) before the product was packet the manufacturer made the mistake
  of leaving the product in a humid area before packing.

  Most candy needs to be properly sealed, just because of the same reason you are pointing out that you experienced. Remember gummy bears are made of sugar and all sugar has moisture in. And sugar attracts moisture. Not sealing the product would allow the candy to attract the moisture that is in the air all around us. Some areas more than others if course.

As for how the manufacturer could improve this from not happening:

- (1) Having the correct balance of ingredients is a must
- (2) Cooking to the correct temperature see link see link on the
  different temperatures and results.

  http://whatscookingamerica.net/Candy/candytemp.htm
- (3)    Producing/Packing in a low humid environment
- (4) Sealing the    product properly in bag.

Comment: thanks for your respond. The problem is that the 2,3,4th point are carefully carried and these points can be easly excluded. The problems lies in the recipe- and mostly with the product coated wit sugar/acid mixture. The question is if maybe changing proportion of its or replacing the ingredients with others could prolong the shel-time( the same time lead to lower moisture)